# How can I extract the number from this BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
<p class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle">
Outram Park
<span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data- 
latitude="1.2783991" data-longitude="103.8408724"></span>
· ~$25/pax
</p>
```

I am trying to extract "$25/pax'. The HTML code is much longer with different pricings. Is there a way I can extract it without extracting the Title and Tags?
I am not trying to key this in:

```
places= soup.find_all('p', class_ = "topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle")
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the places, get `.text`, then `split()`, and get the last element:

```
[place.text.split()[-1] for place in places]
```

If you want to strip off the `~` from start:

```
place.text.split()[-1].lstrip('~')
```

---

**Edit:**

Based on your comment, to remove extraneous words:

```
[place.text.split()[-1].lstrip('~') for place in places if \
    place.text.split()[-1].startswith('~')]
```

In this case, using a simple `for` loop might be proper to avoid doing same thing multiple times:

```
output = []
for place in places:
    value = place.text.split()[-1]
    if value.startswith('~'):
        output.append(value.lstrip('~'))
```

Comment: I got this error   AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'text'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: this was my output ['~$25/pax',
 'Coffee',
 '~$10/pax',
 'Food',
 '~$25/pax',
 'Healthy',
 '~$20/pax',
 'Sandwiches',
 '~$15/pax',
 'Desserts',
 '~$25/pax',
 'Coffee',
 '~$15/pax',
 'Good',
 '~$20/pax',
 'Healthy',
 '~$30/pax',
 'Japanese',
 '~$10/pax',
 'Japanese']

Comment: anyway i can remove the words?

Comment: @Fiz yes. You can remove the words. A list is mutable. If your output is saved as a list called `output`, you can do this: `prices = [price for price in output if 'pax' in price]`. (This will create a new list, so mutability doesn't matter here).

Comment: sorry i meant the word 'Coffee' , etc

Answer (score 0):

You might use select_one with a [css selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and get the [next_sibling](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling):

```
s = """<p class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle">
Outram Park
<span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data- 
latitude="1.2783991" data-longitude="103.8408724"></span>
· ~$25/pax
</p>"""

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(s, 'html.parser')

places= soup.select_one("p.topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle span")
print(places.next_sibling.strip()) # · ~$25/pax
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """ 
<p class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle">
Outram Park
<span class="topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle distance" data- 
latitude="1.2783991" data-longitude="103.8408724"></span>
· ~$25/pax
</p>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

If your html has multiple paragraph tags like the one you mentioned use find_all

```
places= soup.find_all('p', class_ = "topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle")

[soup.get_text().split('~')[1] for place in places ]
```

if your html has only one paragraph tag, use find

```
soup.find('p', class_ = "topVenue-details-info-details-subtitle").text.split('~')[1]
```